# mp4変換時、protocol 'crypto' not on　whitelist　というメッセージが頻発

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

ffmpeg(ffmpeg-201711dd-8f4702a-win64-static)で

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i 入力ファイル.m3u8 -movflags faststart -c copy 出力ファイル.mp4
```

を実行した際、

```
protocol 'crypto' not on　whitelist 'file,http,https,top,tis'!'
```

というメッセージが頻発して 最後は

```
Error when loadig first segment...Invalid data found when processing input
```

で終わりました。もちろん出力ファイルはできませんでした。環境はWin10、マシンはLIFEBOOKAH53/Gです。どなたか解決法を教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: 目的はm3u8ファイルをmp4ファイルに変換することです

Answer (score 2):

> protocol 'crypto' not on whitelist 'file,http,https,tcp,tls'!

エラーメッセージは「入力M3U8ファイル読込みに必要なプロトコル`crypto`が指定されていない」と言っています。オプション`-protocol_whitelist`に`crypto`を追加してみてください。

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto \
       -i 入力ファイル.m3u8 -movflags faststart -c copy 出力ファイル.mp4
```

（`crypto`プロトコルを要求するということは、該当M3U8メディアファイルは暗号化されているようです。MP4ファイルへの変換には、有効な鍵情報が必要になるかもしれません。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記コマンドを一続き(バックスラッシュ抜き)にして打ち込んで実行たところｍｐ４ファイルが保存されていました